# Excel Conditional Formatting To Evaluate Cell To The Left

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, excel-365

I'm having a tough time figuring out this conditional formatting.  I'd like to highlight the entire row if the A column has "Urgent" text.  Pictured is an example of what I'm trying.

EDIT: This question pertains to Excel for web, not for the desktop version.  So far, no thread with similar questions has resolved this issue.

[image: Excel Conditional Formatting]

Comment: `=$A2="Urgent"`.

Comment: as @BigBen Sir ^^^ said, but why do you use `INDIRECT()` here?

Comment: @BigBen that does not work.  Nothing is highlighted.  Rule type is set to Specific Text Containing =$A2="Urgent".  Also tried Cell Value instead of Specific Text and everything gets highlighted like the original post shows.

Comment: You should be using the "use a formula to determine which cells to format" option.

Comment: There are many solved answers to similar questions, if you take some time to research. You will find, like @BigBen Sir has attached them to your post.

Comment: @Rory - That option only exists using the desktop version of Excel.  I'm using the one on Microsoft 365 online that seems to have a lot less options.

Mayukh - I thought 2 hours of research was good enough before posting this question which remains unanswered.  The key here might be that it's not the desktop version and instead the one that works in the browser.. Do I call it Sharepoint?  Microsoft 365?  I don't know, but it's definitely a little different.

Comment: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel-blog/new-conditional-formatting-experience-in-excel-for-the-web/ba-p/3066188 Seems like creating rules based on a formula is supported in Excel for the web.

Comment: @oso0690 alright, but you can see @BigBen Sir has already shared you link. You need to use the right keyword. Since you are using Excel for Web, you could have wrote `How to apply conditional formatting in Excel for Web` and when you do in Google search, it will give you this link at first **[Conditonal_Formatting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/use-conditional-formatting-to-highlight-information-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f#ID0EDH=Web)** on opening the link switch from windows to web, it will certainly help.

Comment: I found out it to be working. Can you refer **[Here](https://imgur.com/gallery/m4qvZ6p)**

Comment: The formula is same as given above by @BigBen Sir. Look at this .gif **[CF](https://imgur.com/gallery/DCBFesE)**

Comment: Thank you all!  I was stuck on the Rule Type.  I kept trying with it set to Highlight Cells With instead of Formula.

Yep, I kept searching for Excel or Excel 365 instead of 'Excel for Web'.  I wasn't really sure what to call it.